# What differences will happen if you use a rectangular baker to bake cookies instead of a tray?

Tags: baking, cookies, cookware

Hey so I have these rectangular bakers that I use to make lasagna. Unfortunately I don't bake cookies that often so I don't have a standard cookie tray. I decided to bake some cookies though so I opted for using those since those are what I have in my disposal. See below

[image]

I just popped them into the oven but I actually didn't consider if this would affect how long they need to cook for since they have that lip that surround the cookies. Will they turn out okay? If I don't get an answer in the next 8 or so minutes I can post what will happen for science.

Comment: I agree with @Megha's answer. *If* you don't get results that you like, you could try turning the pans upside down, and baking the cookies on the bottom of the pan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They should be fine.

It's possible that they'll be a bit gooey, or just a touch underdone.  The high sides of the pan may shield the cookies from the heat, just a little bit.  The glass pans will absorb a little more heat, and so take just a tad longer to heat up - partially balanced by the fact they take a tad longer to cool down, and so might carry over a bit of residual cooking.  Both effects should be pretty minimal, but cookies do bake for a very short amount of time, so the difference may be noticeable in a way that longer-cooking dishes would never notice.

If you look at your cookies, instead of just pulling them out when the time is up, you should notice if they need a touch more baking (I would guess maybe a minute of extra time, if any)... of course, you should probably be doing this anyway, especially if you want to cook them to your desired style (if you prefer a bit softer or a bit crisper, for example).  Light browning on edges or ridges should be a very good cue for done-ness.

Comment: You can also play with placement in the oven to see if higher or lower makes a difference -- higher would get more radiant heat from the top, so they set up faster ... but if the bottoms are still too gooey, it might be better to keep them lower so the pan heats up faster.  (and it might be different for glass / metal / ceramic)

Comment: I almost upvoted the answer but didn't want to spoil the lovely rep of 6,666.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah they came out okay and I believe your conclusions were correct. Interestingly the white pans which were made of porcelain took way longer because they were thicker I think? So I think it took a lot longer for them to get hot. The gray one was fairly thin so it actually cooked pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

I figured I'd post an answer anyways in case people were curious. It seems that the bigger factor was the factor that the white porcelain bakers were a lot thicker and didn't really get hot fast enough. They ended up pretty gooey and I had to put them back into the oven for double the time. Sometimes I just scooped them out and reused the grey pan :/

[image] [image]

Comment: I saw your comment and was going to ask you to post an answer, then I saw the answer!  Thanks for the question and for teaching us from your experience!